# Enums and ComboBoxes in C#

Tags: c#, enums, combobox

I am currently developing a C# application.

I need to use an Enum with a ComboBox to get the selected month. I have the following to create the Enum:

```
enum Months 
{ 
   January = 1,
   February,
   March,
   April,
   May,
   June,
   July,
   August,
   September,
   October,
   November,
   December 
};
```

I then initialise the ComboBox using the following:

```
cboMonthFrom.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Months)));
```

This bit of code works fine however the problem is when I try to get the selected Enum value for the selected month.

To get the Enum value from the ComboBox I have used the following:

```
private void cboMonthFrom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs) 
{
   Months selectedMonth = (Months)cboMonthFrom.SelectedItem;
   Console.WriteLine("Selected Month: " + (int)selectedMonth);
}
```

However, when I try to run the code above it comes up with an error saying `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred`.

What I have done wrong.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
Months selectedMonth = (Months)Enum.Parse(typeof(Months), cboMonthFrom.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

instead of

```
Months selectedMonth = (Months)cboMonthFrom.SelectedItem;
```

Updated with correct changes

Comment: It is not necessary to put strings into the combo box and then parse them back into `Months` values. Just store the `Months` values themselves.

Comment: You are not supposed to store string values to combo box and retrieve them as enumerations. You have to either add enum values as combo box item OR get them as string and convert to enumeration. That is why I suggested to do the latter.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that you're populating combobox with string names (`Enum.GetNames` returns `string[]`) and later you try to cast it to your enum. One possible solution could be:

```
Months selectedMonth = (Months)Enum.Parse(typeof(Months), cboMonthFrom.SelectedItem);
```

I would also consider using existing month information from .Net instead of adding your enum:

```
var formatInfo = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();

var months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(n => formatInfo.MonthNames[n]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
Months selectedMonth = 
    (Months) Enum.Parse(typeof(Months), cboMonthFrom.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is really no reason to use `Enum.GetNames` at all. Why store strings in the ComboBox if you actually want the months?

Just use `Enum.GetValues` instead:

```
foreach (var month in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Months)))
    cboMonthFrom.Items.Add(month);

[...]

// This works now
Months selectedMonth = (Months)cboMonthFrom.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: +1 for putting actual values into combobox, but I would use `AddRange`

Comment: @Snowbear: Already tried it... The shortest way to do that is `combo.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Months)).Cast<object>().ToArray())`, which I thought was unnecessarily roundabout.

Comment: Oh, I thought it would work without `ToArray()`. Hate those methods having `Array` argument where `IEnumerable` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You've stored the names of the months in the combobox, not the int values. Your selected item will be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my one line solution:

comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues( typeof( DragDropEffects ) );

This will get you the selected item:

DragDropEffects effects = ( DragDropEffects ) comboBox1.SelectedItem;

Note: You can use any Enum that you like including your own.