# Compare values with enumeration in c#

Tags: c#, enums

I am framing a simple example of the complex problem that it is part of.

For Easy sake there is a dropdown list which is filled with months of the year.

```
BindDropDown()
{
    ddlColors.DataSource = GetAllMonths();//Returns a List<string> with months
    ddlColors.DataBind();
    //note the drop down only have data fields no value fields no corresponding numeric   values of the months.
}

public enum Months
{
    January   = 1,
    February  = 2,
    March     = 3,
    April     = 4,
    May       = 5,
    June      = 6,  
    July      = 7,  
    August    = 8,  
    September = 9,  
    October   = 10, 
    November  = 11,
    December  = 12
}
```

1. After selecting any of the month value from drop down I have to get the appropriate numeric value by some how matching with the enum that stores its numeric value.

   For Example: value from drop down is May so its corresponding numeric part 5.
2. After getting value from database that will be numeric, some how I have to get the text part of the enum.

   For Example: value from database is 5 so its corresponding text part MAY.

Ho Can I achieve the above scenarios?

Comment: This will help you - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129378/enums-and-combo-boxes-in-c-sharp?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129378/enums-and-combo-boxes-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use [Enum.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/system.enum.format.aspx) to get decimal value by text value of enum:

**EDITED:**

```
 var monthNumber = Enum.Format(typeof(Months), Enum.Parse(typeof(Months), ddlColors.SelectedValue.ToString()),"d");
```

2) Just cast integer to enum and call it's ToString()

```
 var month = ((Months)value).ToString();
```

Comment: it is giving error in the first one saying cannot convert string to int

Comment: @ankur Yes, you should convert your selected value to enum value before using Format. Add Enum.Parse() and this should work

Answer (score 2):

You could cast the integer value to an enum type:

```
int value = 5;
string month = ((Months)value).ToString();
```

alternatively you could use the [`GetName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx) method:

```
int value = 5;
string month = Enum.GetName(typeof(Months), value);
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) You can use [`Enum.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx) for converting a string to an enum (note there is also an overload for doing it case-insensitive).

```
(Months)Enum.Parse(typeof(Months), "May");
```

2.) For converting the value to a string, you just need to call [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z.aspx).

```
((Months)5).ToString();
```